# convolution of \$ e^{-t} \$ and 1-t

Tags: convolution

I cannot solve the convolution based on \$h= e^{-t}\$  for \$ t\ge0 \$ and \$u(t) = 1-t \$ when \$ 0 \le t \le1 \$.
Every time I try I keep getting a factor with \$ te^{-t} \$ whilst the answer shows:
\$ y(t) = 0 \$ if \$t<0\$
\$ y(t) = 2-t-2e^{-t} \$ if \$0\le t\le 1\$ 

\$ y(t) = e^{1-t}-2e^{-t} \$ if \$t>1\$

And I get:

\$ (1-e^{-t})+te^{-t}+(e^{-t}-1) \$ 
After solving the integration by parts with boundaries of 0>t

Comment: `\ge` = \$\ge\$. Also use `$$` to center your formulae.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a better question for Math SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions to be convolved are \$h(t) \$ and \$u(t) \$, as shown in the top two diagrams in the figure below:

[image: Convolution example 1]

Figure source: I drew it.

The third diagram shows the folded \$u(t) \$, i.e., \$u(-t) \$ and the fourth diagram shows the folded and shifted \$u(t) \$, i.e., \$u(-t-\tau) \$. Note that \$\tau \$ is the shift variable. There will be two non-zero overlap integral scenarios: for Overlap A and Overlap B. These are schematically shown in the fifth and sixth diagrams in the figure.

The convolution is given by the following overlap integral:

$$ h(t) * u(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(t) u(-t-\tau) dt $$

For the Overlap A scenario, the convolution integral reduces to:

$$ h(t) * u(t) = \int_{0}^{\tau}h(t) u(-t-\tau) dt $$

while for the Overlap B scenario, the convolution integral reduces to:

$$ h(t) * u(t) = \int_{\tau -1}^{\tau}h(t) u(-t-\tau) dt $$

**Evaluation of convolution integral for Overlap A**

$$\begin{align}
h(t)*u(t) &= \int_0^\tau h(t) u(-t-\tau) dt \\
         &= \int_0^\tau e^{-t}(1+t-\tau)dt    \\
         &= (1-\tau) \int_0^\tau e^{-t}dt + \int_0^\tau te^{-t}dt \\
\end{align}$$

The two definite integrals are just special cases of well known indefinite integrals:

$$\int e^{ax}dx = e^{ax}/a$$ and

$$\int xe^{ax}dx = e^{ax}(ax - 1)/a^2$$

With \$a = -1\$ and \$x \$ replaced by \$t \$ in both integrals, we have

$$\int e^{-t}dt = -e^{-t}$$ and

$$\int te^{-t}dt = e^{-t}(-t - 1) = -e^{-t}(t + 1)$$

Thus, continuing the evaluation for Overlap A:

$$\begin{align}
h(t)*u(t) &= (1-\tau) \left[-e^{-t} \right]_0^\tau + \left[e^{-t}(-t-1)    \right]_0^\tau \\
&= (\tau -1)(e^{-\tau}-1)-[e^{-\tau}(\tau + 1) - 1]  \\
&= \tau e^{-\tau}-e^{-\tau}-\tau+1-\tau e^{-\tau}-e^{-\tau}+1 \\
&= 2-\tau -2e^{-\tau}
\end{align}$$

Replacing \$\tau \$ by \$t \$ then gives the desired result:

$$ y(t) = 2-t -2e^{-t} $$

**Evaluation of convolution integral for Overlap B**

$$\begin{align}
h(t)*u(t) &= \int_{\tau -1}^\tau h(t) u(-t-\tau) dt \\
         &= \int_{\tau -1}^\tau e^{-t}(1+t-\tau)dt    \\
         &= (1-\tau) \int_{\tau -1}^\tau e^{-t}dt + \int_{\tau -1}^\tau te^{-t}dt \\
&= (1-\tau) \left[-e^{-t} \right]_{\tau -1}^\tau + \left[e^{-t}(-t-1)    \right]_{\tau -1}^\tau \\
&= (\tau -1)[e^{-\tau}-e^{-(\tau -1)}]-(\tau +1)e^{-\tau}+\tau e^{-(\tau -1)} \\
&= \tau e^{-\tau}-e^{-\tau}-\tau e^{-(\tau -1)}+e^{-(\tau -1)}-\tau e^{-\tau}-e^{-\tau}+\tau e^{-(\tau -1)} \\
&= e^{-(\tau -1)}-2e^{-\tau}
\end{align}$$

Replacing \$\tau \$ by \$t \$ then gives the desired result:

$$ y(t) = e^{-(t -1)}-2e^{-t} = e^{1 -t}-2e^{-t}  $$

**Summary:**
\$ y(t) = 0 \$ if \$t<0\$
\$ y(t) = 2-t-2e^{-t} \$ if \$0\le t\le 1\$

\$ y(t) = e^{1-t}-2e^{-t} \$ if \$t>1\$

**Check:**
Area under \$h(t) = \int_0^\infty h(t) dt = 1    \$. Area under \$u(t) = \int_0^1 u(t) dt = 1/2    \$. Area under \$y(t) \$ is

$$ \int_0^\infty y(t) dt = \int_0^1 (2-t -2e^{-t}) dt + \int_1^\infty (e^{1 -t}-2e^{-t}) dt = (\frac{2}{e} -\frac{1}{2})+(1-\frac{2}{e}) 
= \frac{1}{2} $$

••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••

**The alternative convolution option**

Suppose it is desired to fold and shift \$h(t) \$ instead of \$u(t) \$. Then the first figure is replaced by this figure:

[image: Convolution 5]

Figure source: I drew it.

The functions to be convolved are \$h(t) \$ and \$u(t) \$, as shown in the top two diagrams in the figure. The third diagram shows the folded \$h(t) \$, i.e., \$h(-t) \$ and the fourth diagram shows the folded and shifted \$h(t) \$, i.e., \$h(-t-\tau) \$. Note that \$\tau \$ is the shift variable. There will be two non-zero overlap integral scenarios: for Overlap A and Overlap B. These are schematically shown in the fifth and sixth diagrams in the figure.

The convolution is given by the following overlap integral:

$$ h(t) * u(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(-t-\tau) u(t) dt $$

For the alternative Overlap A scenario, the convolution integral reduces to:

$$ h(t) * u(t) = \int_{0}^{\tau}h(-t-\tau) u(t) dt $$

while for the alternative Overlap B scenario, the convolution integral reduces to:

$$ h(t) * u(t) = \int_0^1 h(-t-\tau) u(t) dt $$

**Evaluation of convolution integral for Overlap A**

$$\begin{align}
h(t)*u(t) &= \int_0^\tau h(-t-\tau) u(t) dt \\
         &= \int_0^\tau e^{t-\tau} (1-t)dt    \\
&= e^{-\tau} \left[\int_0^{\tau}e^t dt - \int_0^{\tau}te^t dt  \right]  \\
&= e^{-\tau} \left[[e^t]_0^{\tau} - [e^t (t-1)]_0^{\tau}   \right]  \\
&= e^{-\tau} \left[e^{\tau} -1 -\tau e^{\tau} + e^{\tau} -1   \right]  \\
&= e^{-\tau} \left[2e^{\tau} -\tau e^{\tau} -2    \right] \\
         &= 2-\tau -2e^{-\tau} \\
\end{align}$$

Replacing \$\tau \$ by \$t \$ then gives the desired result:

$$ y(t) = 2-t -2e^{-t} $$

**Evaluation of convolution integral for Overlap B**

$$\begin{align}
h(t)*u(t) &= \int_0^1 h(-t-\tau) u(t) dt \\
         &= \int_0^1 e^{t-\tau} (1-t)dt    \\
         &= e^{-(\tau -1)}-2e^{-\tau} \\
\end{align}$$

Replacing \$\tau \$ by \$t \$ then gives the desired result:

$$ y(t) = e^{-(t -1)}-2e^{-t} = e^{1 -t}-2e^{-t}  $$

Comment: Hi,+1 very detailed explanation ,is it always necessary to draw graphs and then figure out different overlap regions ? Can we directly integrate using formula ignoring graphs ?

Comment: @user215805    Thanks for the upvote! It is definitely not necessary (or always necessary) to draw the graphs, but I find it very useful to keep from screwing up! I have done more complicated convolutions by hand and keeping the notation and integration limits sorted out is really the main thing.

Comment: I appreciate the very detailed answer, Since then I had much more practise and now I am able to do these better. But for anyone googling a similar question, this will help them out greatly!

Comment: Glad to be of help! And many thanks for the green checkmark!

Answer (score 2):

Writing down convolution product results in

$$ (h * u)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(t - v)\cdot u(v) dv $$

The parts of the domain we're interested in are:

$$t-v\ge 0 \Rightarrow v \leq t$$ for \$h(t-v)\$

$$0 \leq v \leq 1$$ for \$u(v)\$

We can then find that for \$0 \leq t \leq 1\$:

$$\begin{align}
(h*u)(t) &= \int_0^th(t - v)\cdot u(v) dv \\
         &= \int_0^t e^{-(t-v)}(1-v)dv \\
         &= e^{-t} \left( \int_0^te^vdv - \int_0^tve^vdv \right)
\end{align}$$

Solving the first integral is rather easy:

$$\int_0^te^vdv = \left[e^v\right]_0^t = e^t - 1$$

Solving the second integral requires integration by parts:

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^tve^vdv &= \int_0^tvd(e^v) \\
               &= \left[v\cdot e^v\right]_0^t - \int_0^tve^vdv
\end{align}$$

As you get the same integration as before, you can write:

$$\begin{align}
I &= \left[ v\cdot e^v\right]_0^t - I \\
\Rightarrow 2I &= \left[ v\cdot e^v\right]_0^t \\
\Rightarrow I &= \frac{[v\cdot e^v]_0^t}{2}=\frac{te^t}{2}
\end{align}$$

Plugging it all in yields:

$$
\begin{align}
y(t) &= e^{-t} \left( e^t - 1 - \frac{te^t}{2} \right) \\
     &= 1 - e^{-t} - \frac{t}{2}
\end{align}$$

This answer is off by a factor 2, but it resembles the given answer. I don't see where I was wrong.

For \$t \geq 1\$, you can write

$$
\begin{align}
y(t) &= \int_0^1h(t-v)u(v)dv \\
     &= e^{-t} \left( e - 1 - \frac{e}{2} \right) \\
     &= \frac{e^{1-t}}{2} - e^{-t}
\end{align}$$

This is again off by the same factor of 2 compared to your reference.